# How to duplicate a backup set from one media server to another

Tags: backupexec

I really honestly can't figure out how to do this.

It's easy enough to open Backup Exec and tell it to duplicate the data on one local device onto another local device. What I *cannot* figure out how to do is make it duplicate data from one local device to a *remote* device.

I can connect to the remote BE server, but then I can only access the remove devices. I can connect to the local BE server, but then I can only access the local devices. I can't figure out how the heck to get access to both local and remove devices simultaneously.

Symantec Backup Exec 12.5 for Windows, in case it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, you can't (with BE 12.5 - I haven't used a more recent version).

A Backup Exec Media Server only has access to devices which are attached to it. In short, to duplicate between media servers you have to move the media from one media server to the other, then duplicate it.

Methods of moving media might be: Moving tapes; moving a portable hard drive for backup-to-disk files, or copying them over the network manually; using the SAN Shared Storage Option.

Once you've moved the media to the target system, you'll need to inventory and catalog the media before you can duplicate it.

Comment: Oh, really? So even though it's called a "media server", you can't use it to serve media? Damn... I was hoping I could copy the data this way rather than using the slow-arse Windows SMB protocol over a slow WAN link. :-(